# jQuery - From a nav link to a sliding expandable container

Tags: jquery, menu, nav

The title must be really impossible to understand, sorry for that. Will try to explain what I'm trying to do. Using jQuery to slinding expand a container. 
I have a nav menu, exemple:

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-cat="tech">Technology</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-cat="world">World</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And after that, a temporary hided container:

```
<div id="categories">
<div id="tech">
The category "Tech", Links with images (articles)
</div>
<div id="world">
The category "World", Links with images (articles)
</div>
</div>
```

What the script needs to do is to get the "data-cat" attribute and then slide the respective div that have this "ID". 
If there's any category container, it need to show it (sliding it down). Otherwise if there's any already expanded it needs to slide (like a carousel) to the new toggled category (from left/right).
My problem is that I can't get it to work. And I have no idea on how to do it, actually.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#nav [data-cat]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var cat = $(this).attr('data-cat');
    $('#categories').find('#' + cat).slideDown().siblings().slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
#categories div {
  display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-cat="tech">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-cat="world">World</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="categories">
    <div id="tech">The category "Tech", Links with images (articles)</div>
    <div id="world">The category "World", Links with images (articles)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear mwl, you're a god! haha, but can I be really annoying for a while? If the user click anywhere out the categories div, it will collapse the category div. How can I do it exactly? and thank you very much mate! ♥